# Push notifications in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm planning to use kivy to develop an app related to one of my project. But still I couldn't find a way to make the app run in background and while a certain condition is satisfied I need it to display a push notification in mobile. How can I add push notification feature in kivy? Please let me know if someone know how to make it work. (Note - Even the app is closed in mobile it should run  in background..).

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you how to keep running in the background (because I don't know either) but I can show you how to notify.

by the way,plyer doesn't work as well as windows on android so you should throw with java lib jnius

codes is here:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from jnius import autoclass

def notify(*args):
    AndroidString = autoclass('java.lang.String')
    PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
    NotificationBuilder = autoclass('android.app.Notification$Builder')
    Context = autoclass('android.content.Context')
    Drawable = autoclass('org.test.notify.R$drawable')
    icon = Drawable.icon
    notification_builder = NotificationBuilder(PythonActivity.mActivity)
    notification_builder.setContentTitle(AndroidString('Title'.encode('utf-8')))
    notification_builder.setContentText(AndroidString('Message'.encode('utf-8')))
    notification_builder.setSmallIcon(icon)
    notification_builder.setAutoCancel(True)
    notification_service = notification_service = PythonActivity.mActivity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)
    notification_service.notify(0,notification_builder.build())

class NotifyApp(App):
    def build(self):
    return Button(text="notify", on_press=notify)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NotifyApp().run()
```

if you keep getting errors,look [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Background-Service-using-P4A-android.service)

Answer (score 0):

There is a subsection of the [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer) library that deals with notifications. The [example](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/examples/notification/main.py) implies that you can do

```
import plyer

plyer.notification.notify(
    title="Test Title",
    message="Test Message",
    ticker="Test Ticker",
    app_name="YourAppNameHere"
)
```